# What is the best way of comparing the time component of a date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I know this can be done by:

1. Comparing hour and minutes etc..
2. Comparing date.getTime() % 86400000
3. comparing date.toLocaleTimeString()

is there a straight forward way?

Comment: Should comparing Monday at 1pm to Tuesday at 1pm yield a result indicating that the times are equal or 24 hours apart?

Comment: equal, i mean the date part does not matter just the time matters

Comment: What about fractional seconds? Is 23:11:42.223 the same as 23:11:42.489?

Comment: i was looking for an exact comparison. but the question refers to both. it is just that i find myself comparing times and the code i write never looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare just the time component, you can do:

```
function isTimeEqual(d0, d1) {
  return d0.getHours() == d1.getHours() &&
         d0.getMinutes() == d1.getMintues() &&
         d0.getSeconds() == d1.getSeconds() &&
         d0.getMilliseconds() == d1.getMilliseconds();
}
```

You may not care about the milliseconds.

If you know that daylight saving is never observed at the location, or the times are UTC, you could do:

```
var msPerDay = 24*60*60*1000;
return d0 % msPerDay == d1 % msPerDay;
```

or

```
return !((d0 - d1) % 8.64e7);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is the second one. But it can be done like this.

```
var d1 = new Date("10/10/2008 12:00");
var d2 = new Date("10/12/2008 12:30");
var diff = (d2-d1) % 86400000;
```

If you want it to work for d1 > d2,

```
var d1 = new Date("10/11/2010 12:00");
var d2 = new Date("10/10/2010 12:30");

d1.setFullYear(d2.getFullYear());
d1.setMonth(d2.getMonth());
d1.setDate(d2.getDate());
var diff = d2-d1;
```